# How to fix function missing 2 required positional arguments - when it's already being defined

Tags: python-3.x

I have two files for generating a singly linked list.

The first file has two classes. One creates the head, and the other adds other nodes onto it. The second right now, opens a file, reads through it, and puts each word into my insert function and the insert function creates a node out of it.

My problem is that my insert function wants 'self', and 'x', even though I defined the class on the other file so it shouldn't need that, right?

Here is my code for the other file (right now I'm testing so it's just trying to insert a single word into my insert function).

```
Linked_List
node = Linked_List_node
node.insert('insert_this_into_function')
```

and this is what my classes look like. (Also I'm unsure about the first line - Linked_List. I know I need to create the head node somehow, but can't figure out how to do it.

```
class Linked_List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None


class Linked_List_node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.name = value
        self.next = None

    def print(self):
        p = self.head
        while p is not None:
            p.print()
            p = p.next

    def insert(self, x):
        """"""
        p = self.head
        q = None
        done = False
        while not done:
            if self.head == None:
                t = Linked_List_node(x)
                self.head = t
                self.head = Linked_List_node(x)
                done = True
            elif p == None:
                t = Linked_List_node(x)
                q.next = t
                done = True
            elif x < p.data:
                if self.head == p:
                    t = Linked_List_node(x)
                    t.next = p
                    self.head = t
                    done = True
                else:
                    t = Linked_List_node(x)
                    t.next = p
                    q.next = t
                    done = True
            q = p
            p = p.next
```

Comment: There are small issues in your class, check my answer on how to fix them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed your classes slightly. To begin with, the Linked_List_node will have `data` and `next` attributes.

```
class Linked_List_node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.data = value
        self.next = None
```

We will then have `Linked_List` which keeps the list of nodes as below. For insert, we iterate till we reach end of list by checking `if p!= None: p = p.next`

```
class Linked_List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def print(self):
        #Iterate till you reach end of linked list
        p = self.head
        while p is not None:
            #print data
            print(p.data)
            p = p.next

    def insert(self, x):
        """"""
        p = self.head
        q = None
        done = False
        while not done:
            if self.head == None:
                t = Linked_List_node(x)
                self.head = t
                self.head = Linked_List_node(x)
                done = True
            elif p == None:
                t = Linked_List_node(x)
                q.next = t
                done = True
            elif x < p.data:
                if self.head == p:
                    t = Linked_List_node(x)
                    t.next = p
                    self.head = t
                    done = True
                else:
                    t = Linked_List_node(x)
                    t.next = p
                    q.next = t
                    done = True
            q = p
            #We reach the end of linked list to insert when we hit None
            if p!= None:
                p = p.next
```

I then call the classes like below.

```
head = Linked_List_node(1)
ll = Linked_List()
ll.head = head
ll.insert(2)
ll.insert(3)
ll.print()
#1
#2
#3
```

Comment: Why did you set ll = to Linked_List()? Doesn't it have to be Linked_List_node because the node is the one that has insert?

Comment: ll is the data structure to hold the linked list nodes, also I have moved around the definitions so that node only has data and next, and linked list takes care of print and insert, check my code again